# How can I pass the iteration number to a fixture in Google Test?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

With Google Test, I'm using `TEST_P` to define a fixture. I later use it with a long list of test cases:

```
INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(
    MyTest,
    MyFixture,
    ::testing::ValuesIn(my_parameters()));
```

Inside the fixture, I need to be able to access the iteration number of the current test case. I.e. - the third test case being run as part of this `INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P` will be able to access its iteration number as `2` (or `3` if it's 1-based indexing).

I would like to avoid hard coding these running numbers inside the parameter objects.

Does this functionality exist in Google Test?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `::testing::UnitTest::GetInstance()->current_test_info()->value_param()` to obtain the part of the test's name that reflects the parameter.

Real question is: why do you need it?